# Updating field of selected results in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to write a script that will update a field with 2 values (Wrong/Ok) when specific conditions are met.
This is what I've come up so far, but I can't get it to work..

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Mukono_Polygon') 
layer = layers[0]
it = layer.getFeatures()
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('PlotArea')
idy = layer.fieldNameIndex('Pr')
idz = layer.fieldNameIndex('CTRL')

layer.startEditing()
for feat in it:
  if feat.attributes()[idx] <> '888.8888' and feat.attributes()[idx] <> '999.9999' and feat.attributes()[idy] > '120':
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.attributes()[idz], 'Wrong')
  elif feat.attributes()[idx] <> '888.8888' and feat.attributes()[idx] <> '999.9999' and feat.attributes()[idy] > '80':
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.attributes()[idz], 'Ok')
  else:
    print 'Cant find specific entries'

layer.commitChanges()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 23, in 
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

If remove change the line 23 to print '', the script doesnt do anything.

I chose to get the fields by name instead of their number index because it's different from shapefile to shapefile.

Comment: It looks like your error is originating from a file being prematurely closed or not opened in the correct mode. Is there more of the code that you are not showing that includes opening a file?

Comment: The [QgsVectorLayer::changeAttributeValue()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aaf39ac56bb98c118b881e512e07c5d76) method requires a `features id`, `field` and the `new value`. Try using `layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), idz, 'Wrong')`

Comment: @1saac No, this is entire code.
Just tried that Joseph, no effect...

Comment: @kidd - What field types are `idx` and `idy`? If they are non-string, remove the string quotes around your values in your `if` statements. E.g. `if feat.attributes()[idx] <> 888.8888 and feat.attributes()[idx] <> 999.9999 and feat.attributes()[idy] > 120:`

Comment: `feat` objects are dictionnary like, so you can change all `feat.attributes()[id]` to `feat['field_name']`.

Comment: Ty Joseph for notice, [idz] was non-string. I removed the variables as said by @YoLecomte replacing `feat.attributes()[id]` with `feat['field_name']` but now I get a different error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 16, in 
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsVectorLayer.changeAttributeValue(int, int, QVariant, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPyNullVariant'`

it's on this line

`layer.changeAttributeValue(feat['CTRL'], 'Wrong')`

Comment: the first argument of `changeAttributeValue` must the id of the feature. so you need something like `layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('field_name'), new_value)`

Comment: That was great. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much Joseph And YoLecomte. Dunno how to mark both your answers correct. I added + rep. I will post full working code for anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to YoLecomte and Joseph. Here is the final code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Mukono_Polygon') 
layer = layers[0]
it = layer.getFeatures()

layer.startEditing()
for feat in it:
  if feat['PlotArea'] <> 888.8888 and feat['PlotArea'] <> 999.9999 and feat['Pr'] > 120:
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('CTRL'), 'Wrong')
  elif feat['PlotArea'] <> 888.8888 and feat['PlotArea'] <> 999.9999 and feat['Pr'] > 80:
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('CTRL'), 'Ok')
  else:
    print 'Cant find specific entries'

layer.commitChanges()
```